# How to derive the big O of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

This is the algorithm:

```
for i ← 1 to n by 1 do
    for j ← 1 to i by 1 do
        for k ← 1 to j by 1 do
           x = x + 1
        end
    end
end
```

The number of times the inner loop iterate, depends on the outer loops... so how can the time complexity be derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm increases  with the <sup>th</sup> [tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number). This is because the loops can be seen as sums over a range:

- The outer loop: ∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub>
- The middle loop: ∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub>
- The inner loop: ∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub>
- The inner statement: runs in constant time, so that counts as 1 operation.

This means the inner statement runs this many times:

∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub> ( ∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub> ( ∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub>
1 ) )

The inner sum really is , so we can write:

∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub> ( ∑<sub><sub>= 1</sub></sub>
 )

We recognise this expression as the tetrahedral number (see formula at above link to Wikipedia)

This double sum is ( + 1)( + 2)/6 = θ(³)

Another way to see this, is that the loops lead to combinations for , , and  where they appear in non-decreasing order. So the number of times `x = x + 1` is executed, corresponds to the number of ways we can select a **multiset** of three values from the range 1.., allowing duplicates. This number is [*" multichoose 3"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition), which leads to the same formula.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, but could you please show me your method of working this out. Like how did you work out x increases with the nth tetrahedral number. I'm new to this so sorry if I'm being dumb, your help is much appreciated

Comment: Sorry it was not clear. I have expanded the answer. Does this clarify it?

Comment: yes that has clarified it, thank you